# Find current location

Tags: java, android

I can't find the current location, always find my last location.

I have to change what.

Please help.

My project homework for school

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    gpstxt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtgps);
    buttonGPS = (Button) findViewById(R.id.gpsbtn);

    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        return;
    }
    final Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(locationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

    buttonGPS.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onLocationChanged(location);
        }
    });

}

private void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    double longtitude = location.getLongitude();
    double latitude = location.getLatitude();
    gpstxt.setText("Enlem:" + latitude + "\n" + "Boylam:" + longtitude);
}

}
```

Not the last location output.
I want to find the current location using gps.

Answer (score 0):

You should not be using locationManager.getLastKnownLocation()

Rather you should subscribe to location updates.

You can check this out for more details on the implementation.

https://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using the `getLastKnownLocation()` method which provides you with the last known location of the user.

Instead, you should be using the `requestLocationUpdates()` method present in the locationManager package.

Something like this should work :

```
// Acquire a reference to the system Location Manager
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

// Define a listener that responds to location updates
LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
      // Called when a new location is found by the network location provider.
      makeUseOfNewLocation(location);
    }

    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}

    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}

    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
  };

// Register the listener with the Location Manager to receive location updates
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
```

Reference : https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html